# Can someone figure out my encryption secret and iv if they have payload and encrypted string?

Tags: javascript, node.js, encryption, cryptojs

I use `crypto` by node.js to encode and decode payloads

just fyi here is how i do it:

```js
export const encode = (payload) => {
  const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-256-cbc', env.SECRET, env.IV);
  const encyptedString = cipher.update(JSON.stringify(payload), 'utf-8', 'hex') + cipher.final('hex');

  return encyptedString;
};

export const decode = (encyptedString) => {
  const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv(
    'aes-256-cbc',
    env.SECRET,
    env.IV,
  );
  const decryptedValue = decipher.update(encyptedString, 'hex', 'utf-8') + decipher.final('utf-8');

  return JSON.parse(decryptedValue);
};
```

now, if someone has access to both the payload object and encrypted string would they be able to figure out my `env.SECRET` and `env.IV`?

Comment: S. [*Why is AES resistant to known-plaintext attacks?*](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1512/why-is-aes-resistant-to-known-plaintext-attacks) BTW, a constant IV is a vulnerability. For each encryption, a random IV should be generated (which must be passed to the decrypting side, usually concatenated with the ciphertext).

Comment: thanks. is then okay for `IV` to be publicly accessible as well along with payload and encrypted string?

Comment: The IV is not secret, so it can be concatenated with the ciphertext without any concern. Important is that key/IV pairs are not reused, which is prevented with random IVs.

Answer (score 0):

No it's not possible to determine by just payload object and encrypted string unless you use a very simple secret and iv like 123456789 in such case it will be pretty easy to figure it out by brute force.